# Icon not shown in Dropdown menus in Twenty Seventeen Theme

Tags: menus, dropdown, icon, theme-twenty-seventeen

I guess I removed the image used for the dropdown menu while cleaning up my site that uses the Twenty Seventeen theme.Now it shows nothing (or a box) next to a dropdown menu which is not understandable by most of my website visitors. I tried to find the option to add icon in the menu section but there's none. Here is the concerned [website](https://cyberneticsrobo.com/)

I've added two screenshots. One 'desktop view' and the other 'mobile view'.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

[image: menu-desktop view]

[image: menu-mobile view]

[image: no icon option]

Answer (score 0):

It's not images, its fontawesome icons, and the fontawesome library is not being called. so you can add the below code to your theme functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_load_fa' );
function enqueue_load_fa() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'load-fa', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
}
```

thats how the current icons for the menus will be showing.

Comment: Thanks Zee. I'll try your solution :)